# Space in column name Talend

Tags: talend

I want to make a csv file that I can upload in my Google Calendar.
The mandatory headers for a file to upload are

Subject, Start date, Start time

But in Talend you can't make a column name with a space between the words, anybody know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can generate the first line with a "tFixedFlowInput" and complete your CSV file without column titles by changing in your output component the parameter "Include Header".

Don't forget to check the parameter "append" when you insert your data after